# How to convert a tuple of bytes to an integer and back?

Tags: python, string, binary, tuples, decimal

**Problem:** I would like to get

```
(7,5,3) => 000001110000010100000011 => 460035  
  also the converse, i.e.,   
460035 => 000001110000010100000011 => (7,5,3)
```

Here is the the program I have tried:

```
L=(7,5,3) # here L may vary each time.
a=0
for i in range(3):
    a=bin(a << 8) ^ bin(L[i])
print a
```

But It gives error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'str' and 'str'`
How can I do this?

Comment: To raise a power in python, you should use `**` instead of `^`. Your operands are also of type `str` (string) on which `**` won't work

Comment: This is not power, it is bit wise xor operation @Bazingaa

Comment: What is the relation between `000001110000010100000011` and `460035` ?

Comment: decimal of 000001110000010100000011 is 460035 @ BlackBeard

Comment: Remove the calls to `bin` to make direct conversion from tuple to integer and after that convert from integer to binary string.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you it works. How can I do the reverse process?

Comment: `a=int(bin(a << 8)[2:],2) ^ int(bin(L[i])[2:], 2)` Try This

Comment: [Bitwise operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=bitwise#binary-bitwise-operations) work with integers:  but [`bin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) returns a string. Probably you don't need to use `bin` in the first place: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/bitwise_operators_example.htm

Comment: More on bitwise operations on integers: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bitwise#bitwise-operations-on-integer-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel. If you'd seen the links to docs that I provided in the comments, you could find these useful methods there: [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bitwise#int.from_bytes) and [`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bitwise#int.to_bytes). We can use them like this:

```
input = (7, 5, 3)
result = int.from_bytes(input, byteorder='big')
print(result)
>>> 460035

print(tuple(result.to_bytes(3, byteorder='big')))
>>> (7, 5, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should perform bit operations on the numbers rather than the converted strings:

```
L=(7,5,3)
a=0
for i in L:
    a <<= 8
    a |= i
print(bin(a), a)
```

This outputs:

```
0b1110000010100000011 460035
```

Reversal:

```
a = 460035
L = []
while True:
    L.append(a & 0xff)
    a >>= 8
    if not a:
        break
L = tuple(L[::-1])
print(L)
```

This outputs:

```
(7, 5, 3)
```